# First non-repeating character in a stream of characters

Tags: java, string, algorithm, arraylist, collections

The question asks us to find new string B.

B is formed such that we have to find first non-repeating character each time a character is inserted to the stream and append it at the end to B. If no non-repeating character is found then append '#' at the end of B.

```
Example:
    "a"      -   first non repeating character 'a'
    "ab"     -   first non repeating character 'a'
    "aba"    -   first non repeating character 'b'
    "abad"   -   first non repeating character 'b'
    "abadb"  -   first non repeating character 'd'
    "abadbc" -   first non repeating character 'd'
```

Can someone help me out where my code went wrong. my logic is to use substring function of string and find the unique character and add it to arraylist and print the entire arraylist.

```
public class Solution
{
    public String solve(String A) 
    {
        ArrayList<Character>a=new ArrayList<Character>();
        String res="";

        for(int i=0;i<A.length();i++)
        { 
            String ss=A.substring(0,i+1);
            String ue=uniqueCharacters(ss);
           // System.out.println(ue);
      
           if(ue!="") a.add(ue.charAt(0));
           else a.add('#');
        } 
     
        for(Character j:a) res+=j;
    
        return res;
    } 

    public static String uniqueCharacters(String test)
    {
        String temp = "";
    
        for (int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++)
        {
            char current = test.charAt(i);
            if (temp.indexOf(current) < 0) temp = temp + current;
            else temp = temp.replace(String.valueOf(current), "");
        }

        return temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. In your case: dont just tell us "something is wrong". Tell us what exactly isnt working with your code.

Comment: And note: that is how you should approach your assignment in the first place: start with small tests, and see what happens. And as soon as you get to a result that is unexpected, use a debugger, or simply: more print statements to figure where your code deviates from your expectations.

Comment: Finally: please consider to use more meaningful names. Dont use abbreviations like ss ue or meaningless names like test or temp. The names are for your human readers. Make sure they SAY what the variable is about. And be more diligent about indenting and formatting. Your code is much harder to read, just because it is so sloppily indented.

Comment: Can you explain where your code is going wrong? It is working for the sample input. `Input: "abadbc"`  `Output: aabbdd` which is not wrong. *If you think its wrong, kindly explain why*. I should add, *the problem can be solved in more efficient manner*.

Comment: You are removing a character from `temp` when you encounter it a second time, which implies that it will appear as unique when encountering it a third time (or on every odd occurrence). Further, you should not compare strings using `==` nor `!=`. You have to use `equals`. Though, in the case of `ue!=""`, you can also use `!ue.isEmpty()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be better to use a `Set` to detect unique characters in the input string using the result of `Set::add` which returns `false` if no element has been actually added to the set, and a `Queue` to maintain the non-repeated characters.

When a repeated (non-unique) character is detected, it gets removed from the queue and if necessary, `"#"` is applied as a placeholder.  And if a unique character is detected, it is just added to the queue.

Example implementation:

```java
public static String solve(String str) {
    // verify the input
    if (null == str || str.isEmpty()) {
        return str;
    }
    
    Set<Character> previous = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    Queue<Character> nonRepeated = new LinkedList<>();
    
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // use the first character
    char curr = str.charAt(0);
    previous.add(curr);
    nonRepeated.add(curr);
    sb.append(curr);
    
    for (int i = 1, n = str.length(); i < n; i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        
        if (!previous.add(c)) { // duplicate character found
            nonRepeated.remove(c);
            if (nonRepeated.isEmpty()) {
                curr = '#';
            } else { // get the next non-repeated character
                curr = nonRepeated.peek();
            }
        } else { // unique element is detected
            if (curr == '#') {
                curr = c;
            }
            nonRepeated.add(c);
        }
        
        sb.append(curr);
    }
    
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Tests:

```java
for (String t : Arrays.asList("abadbc", "abcdba", "aaabbbacab")) {
    System.out.printf("input: %s --> %s%n----%n", t, solve(t));
}
```

Output:

```
input: abadbc --> aabbdd
----
input: abcdba --> aaaaac
----
input: aaabbbacab --> a##b###ccc
----
```

Answer (score 0):

When you encounter a char a 2nd time you remove it from the unique characters (1), but if there was a 3rd of that character it would be added again (2).

```
public static String uniqueCharacters(String test)
    {
        String temp = "";
    
        for (int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++)
        {
            char current = test.charAt(i);
            if (temp.indexOf(current) < 0) temp = temp + current; <---- (2)
            else temp = temp.replace(String.valueOf(current), ""); <----- (1)
        }

        return temp;
    }
```

Solution count the number of chars and then return only those whose count is 1 (one).

Answer (score 0):

**Simple approach to find non repeating character from string using java 8 :**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s="AAHJAKTMJ";

    Map<String, Long> counts = Arrays.stream(s.split(""))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i, Collectors.counting()));

    // Display repeating elements and their counts
    counts.forEach((element, count) -> {
        if (count == 1) {
            System.out.println("Non Repeating Character From String: " +element);
        }
    });
}
```